# icant send file in nuxtjs 3 via form-data

Tags: multipartform-data, nuxtjs3

try to send file form-data via nuxtjs3 but it not send any data
I want to send a file to the server
I send the data correctly from the client side to the nuxt server side
I created a file in the next server section to handle and receive and send files and parameters with nodejs, which is as follows:

```
import { readFiles } from "h3-formidable";
import FormData from "form-data";
import fs from "fs";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const token = getCookie(event, "token");
  const query = getQuery(event);

  const {
    public: { apiBase },
  } = useRuntimeConfig();

  const { fields, files } = await readFiles(event, {
    includeFields: true,
  });
  // console.log(fields, "fields");
  // console.log(files, "files");
  // return "data";
  try {
    let formNodeData = new FormData();
    for (let index = 0; index < files.images.length; index++) {
      formNodeData.append(
        "images[]",
        fs.createReadStream(files.images[index].filepath)
      );

    }
   
    formNodeData.append("name", fields.name[0]);

    formNodeData.append("city", "tehran");

    const data = await $fetch(`${apiBase}${query.url}`, {
      method: "POST",
      body:formNodeData,

      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });
    console.log(formNodeData, " this is Form data in server api rental");
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
});
```

name and city in this code sent null ? why ? I left those two fields, city and name, for testing.
The problem is that no data is sent to the final server, neither the file nor the city and name

Comment: If you are open to an alternative solution. You can use readMultipartFormData from h3 utils which can be found here.https://github.com/unjs/h3/tree/5f503c23286e431a249bf379b6bb779d62e71059

There is also a video for uploading files to server using that h3. 
https://youtu.be/mQxY3tL7-pg?si=lPkXJ0u1jYdNEp5W